# View Result tree is not showing a correct request as in script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In the script we are using a PUT request as shown in below image

[image]

But when we run this, it is showing it as a GET request as shown in the below image

[image]

Due to this request is failing with a 400 bad request response code.

I am using Jmeter 5.5

Answer (score 0):

If you expand this Sample Result to see its sub results you will see your initial PUT request followed by at least one [redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) so View Results Tree listener is "showing the correct result", the fact that your PUT request fails is rather connected with a problem in your script, most probably you're simply not authorized due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) or something like this.

So visit previous results and inspect their response data to ensure that your script is doing what is supposed to be doing, the fact that the request is "green" indicates only that [HTTP Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) is below 400, it doesn't necessarily mean that it's successful.